# How can I edit the style of button with pyside2?

Tags: python, pyside2

Now I use Pyside2 to create a UI, but the style of the button is very old, just like winxp. I want it to be newer, but I don't know how to do it, do anyone know how to do?

now ui

[image]

what I want

[image]

My code is just like that:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.open_directory_button = QPushButton("打开文件夹")
self.open_directory_button.clicked.connect(self.open_directory_button_clicked)
        self.path_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.path_layout.addWidget(self.path_edit)
        self.path_layout.addWidget(self.open_directory_button)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.path_layout)
        self.frame = QWidget(self)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see the style of the second image is the "fusion" so a possible solution is:

```py
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle("fusion") # <----

# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do it!

Comment: Yeah! But I find only "windows" and "fusion" work, and "windowsvista" is not useful, but qt`s documents says it can work, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the setStyleSheet, see this:

```
open_directory_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
open_directory_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:pressed{image:url(C:\image.png); border:none} QPushButton:hover{image:url(C:\image_hover.png); border:none}")
```